# How to buy Spivak's A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, soft-question, books

This sounds a bit stupid, but how can I buy Spivak's *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry* (the third edition)? It does not seem to be available on Amazon (at least most of it is not for a reasonable price). I am particularly interested in buying it in the UK. However, buying it in the US might also be an option.

Comment: https://pctex.org/mathpop/ https://www.mathpop.com/

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler Am I just supposed to send them an email?

Comment: "the last edition" being the 3rd edition?

Comment: @DavidRoberts I think it is indeed the 3rd one.

Comment: @YiftachBarnea ok, thanks, I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Find it on the Internet for free and buy when it is available for a reasonable price. It seems hard to get even in the US: vol 3 hardcover on Amazon is for $7,586.00.

Comment: ebay is also a good resource when it comes to used books

Comment: ABE Books seem to have the individual volumes: see https://www.abebooks.com/

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz I have been doing this for many years, I recently ordered parts 4 and 5  and got one of them. But the others are never in reasonable price.

Comment: I should add you can from time to time find some of the old editions for reasonable price including on ABE, but not the new ones.

Comment: Just write to Spivak: https://pctex.org/mathpop/

Comment: Find an electronic copy and then print it.

Comment: @FrancoisZiegler: would you like to make your comment an answer? Note that the first link is dead, but the second link to Publish or Perish is very much alive, and mathpop.com now provide links to much-more reasonably priced versions on Amazon ($50 for volume 3 when I clicked today).

Comment: Because Michael Spivak passed away in 2020, I don't think it is possible to get a reply from writing him.

Answer (score 4):

(Comment $\to$ answer at Willie Wong’s suggestion.)

The now-overhauled Publish or Perish web site, [https://mathpop.com](//mathpop.com), lists nine of their books with links to Amazon pages. That includes *Comprehensive Introduction* but unfortunately not [all the books](//openlibrary.org/publishers/Publish_or_Perish) they once published.